# Copy Observable Collection to another using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, generic-list, observable

I'm attempting to create a method which will allow me to copy observable collection to another using reflection. The observable collection would be part of the DTO which i am copying, and hence i need to uniquely identify whether its an Observable Collection /List.

Thank you..
Rithesh

Comment: Very unclear if you have problem with anything or just for some reason stating your intentions on SO. Code you have problem with may make this question answerable...

Comment: Alexi, Thanks for your reply. My doubt was how to identify the ObservableCollections or List collection while using reflection to copy a dto object to another. The DTo object will contain data types such as datetime, as well as ObservableCollection<dateTime> .. here i need to identify the incomming data type.

I have used IsArray to identify the arrays, but the observable collection doesn't land inside that condition.

Comment: What about IEnumerable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying collection to list can be done with `Enumerable.ToList` extension method.

If you want to detect type via reflection - [Type.IsGenericType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isgenerictype.aspx) and [Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx) will let you detect if type of given object is `ObservableCollection<T>`. Than [Type.GetGenericArguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will give the exact type. At that point you should be able to create your own collection of element of that type and copy elements from original collection into new one.